# Cordova/Ionic : The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

While trying to run the ionic `$ ionic cordova build android` I get the following error :

**"The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined"**

Output of the `$ ionic info` is below. Can someone help me with a solution for this ?

````
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 7 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.3.0 

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.11.3
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61```
````

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: **Adding the below source-file tags in config.xml solved my problem**.    

```<source-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
<source-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
<source-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
<source-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
<source-file src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />```